# Xpath expression to get href. Not just anchor text

Tags: php, xpath

Playing around with xpath expressions trying to learn it. I found a code snippet, and adjusted it a little. What I'm trying to do is get every link on a page.

```
$baseurl = "http://www.example.com";
$html = file_get_contents($baseurl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$ahrefs = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach ($ahrefs as $ahref) { 
    echo $ahref->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```

But now I'm grabbing the anchor text. I want the `href` part. Maybe even both. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the href you have to access the [attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) property of the node

```
echo $ahref->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
//a/@href
```

No additional code (except for the evaluation of this expression) is necessary.

Comment: This worked for me! Generic XPath solution rather than PHP-specific awkward code.

Comment: @dhalperi, Of course. XPath is portable and an XPath expression can be used with most programming languages unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $ahref->getAttribute('href') . "<br />";
```